# How to write unit test for VIs that contain "Tick Count (ms)" LabVIEW function?

Tags: unit-testing, labview

There is a VI that its outputs (indicators) depend not only on the inputs but also on the values of "Tick Count" functions. The problem is that it does not produce the same output for the same inputs. each time that I run it, it gives different outputs. so the unit test that only captures inputs and outputs would fail. So the question is how to write a unit test for this situation?

I cannot include the VI in the question as it contains several subVIs and the "tick count" functions are spread through all level of its subVIs.

EDIT1: I wrote a wrapper that subtracts the output values of two consecutive runs in order to eliminate the base reference time (which is undefined in this function) but it spoils the outputs.

Comment: How does the tick count (or local computer time) change the output of your code? Could you share a snippet of the code that is malfunctioning.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have been given a very difficult task, as the function you've been asked to test is [non-deterministic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx) and it is [challenging to write unit tests against non-deterministic code](http://martinfowler.com/articles/nonDeterminism.html).

There are some ways to test non-deterministic functions: for example one could test that a random number generator produced  values uniformly distributed to some tolerance, or test that a clock-setting function matched an ntp server to some tolerance. But I think you're team will be happier if you can make the underlying code deterministic.

Your idea to use conditional disable is good, but I would add the additional step of creating a wrapper VI and then search and replace all native Tick Count with it. This way you can do any modifications to Tick Count in one place. If for some reason the code actually uses the tick count for something other than profiling (for example, it is being used to seed a pseudorandom number generator) you can have your "test/debug" case that read from a Notifier that you are injecting a set of fake tick counts into from your testing code. Notifiers work great for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an (optional input) that allows you to override the tick count value. Give it a default value of -1, and in the VI you can use the tick count value if it's input is -1.
However I have never seen code relying on tick count.

Comment: I don't want/not allowed to change the VI under test (and make it probably more complicated). I have been asked to write unit tests without changing/modifying the VIs.

Comment: Another way is to put the tick count function into Conditional Disable structure in Default case and put proper value(s) in UNIT_TEST case of that but again it requires to change the VI under test which I am not supposed to do.